# Summing based on >=date

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, sum

I am creating a running targeting program for the staff at work and I am stuck on running a progressive tally.

I'll explain what I have first.

```
A1=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1)
A2==TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1
A3=(A1+7), A4=(A2+7)
```

It gives me a progressive date log of 7 days.

Column `B` is the names of the salesperson.

`C1` = Total sales (this will be updated every day automatically from a generated report using a data link).

What I need is for sales to copy from `C1` (TOTAL SALES) to `C2`, this is easy enough. Once the first 7 days have gone, I need to start summing up the sales from the 8th day onwards and put into `C3`. So if `A3` is greater than or equal to `A1`, I need `C3` to equal sales over and above `C2`. eg. Between the 1st and 7th we sell $10000, `C2` = $10000. From the 8th to the 14th, we sell another $5000. I need `C2` to show $10000, and `C3` to show $5000. From the 15th to the 21st we sell $7000. `C2` = $10000, `C3` = $5000, `C4` = $7000, `C1` =$22000.

Forgot to add, once a date has passed I need it to lock sales for that period. So if on the 7th we were on the $10000, Once the figures for the 8th are imported, I need the $1000 to be locked and the additions done for the following week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should give you total sales for days previous than today: `=SUMIF(A2:A10;"<=" & TODAY();C2:C10)`.

For locking cells I guess you need some VBA. Assuming that you want to lock only `Column C` from `row 2` onward and that you have locked the worksheet with the password "qwerty":

```
Sub lockCells()
  Const myPassword As String = "qwerty"
  Range("C2").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect 'Password:=myPassword
  Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value < Now() And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) <> vbNullString
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Locked = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
  Loop
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=myPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

If there are other people who will use the spreadsheet maybe you want to hide the project for viewing so they are not able to see the password...

Comment: The first part work nicely. So in theory, can I do something along the lines of =IF(C4=Today(),D4=(what ever the sales were at that point?)

Comment: I do not know how you have structured your worksheet, but if you have a formula which sums up your sales in C4 you should copy them as values before you lock the cell because when you change the value of their numbers the total in C4 will reflect that change even if it is locked. Locking a cell means that you cannot change only what is typed in that cell.

Comment: I have added the copy as values in column C in my previous code. Please, have a look.